# how to make a javascript input number positive and negative number

Tags: javascript

Hi, I am wondering how I would be able to do this code. I have an idea on how to make the javascript code, but I'm not sure if my code is correct. The question I have been given is:

> Design and develop a javascript program that will determine if input
>   number is positive and negative.Consider zero(0) as
>   positive(considering that it contains no negative sign).

here is my javascript code, I'm not sure if this is correct based on the question above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>activity 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var stringNumber = prompt("Enter Number: ", "");
    stringNumber = parseInt(stringNumber);
    if(stringNumber >=80){
      document.write("Positive");
    }else{
      document.write("Negative");
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

any answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does 80 come from? `if(stringNumber >= 0)`  - you should also look at providing 10 as the second argument to parseInt().

Comment: sorry just my idea on the 80

Comment: The question is flawed. _"Design and develop a javascript program that will determine if input number is positive and negative."_ No number can be both positive AND negative. Except sometimes for zero, but the question already says to consider that a positive.

Comment: ahh yes im just wondering when i input -1 it now goes to negative

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the number is greater than or equal to 0

```
if(stringNumber >= 0)
{
    document.write("Positive");
}
else
{
    document.write("Negative");
}
```

Comment: i have question is that ok i use parseInt(stringNumber) ?? when i remove the parseInt but still the same answer..

Comment: `parseInt` will convert the string input into an integer data type. Since the right hand side of this comparison is a number, javascript will convert the left hand side to one as well. So no, the parseInt is not necessary, but good practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
var theNumber = prompt("Enter a Number:");

if (theNumber < 0) {
   document.write("Negative");
}
else {
   document.write("Positive");
}
```

Comment: Things entered in the prompt are strings. You need to call parseInt or parseFloat to convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Why you comparing number with 80? It should be 0

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var stringNumber = prompt("Enter Number: ", "");
    stringNumber = parseInt(stringNumber);
    if(stringNumber >=0){
      document.write("Positive");
    }else{
      document.write("Negative");
    }
  </script>
```

And it work fine

Comment: yah sorry on that i was just thinking like when i input a lower number outputs negative

Answer (score 0):

Positive, negative & NaN:

```
var stringNumber = prompt("Enter Number: ");

stringNumber = parseInt(stringNumber, 10); 

if (isNaN(stringNumber)) {
    document.write("Not a Number");
} else if(stringNumber >=0) {
    document.write("Positive");
} else {
    document.write("Negative");
}
```